# Slidetoggle() function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in web development and facing a problem while applying jquery function slideToggle() in a select options feature of HTML5. The following is the code I'm using the slideToggle() function with:

```js
//Script for select element

var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.setAttribute("ID", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  b.setAttribute("ID", "selectItems");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/

document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);

//select dropdown slide function
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select-selected").click(function(){
    $("#selectItems").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: myTrench
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

/*hide default select in IE8*/
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 40px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-color: #212121 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #212121 transparent;
  top: 20px;
}

/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #212121;
  padding: 30px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 5px
  }

.select-selected {
 background-color: #06FFFB;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #212121
 }


/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #06FFFB;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: #85FCFF;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 35%; top: 5%">
<span>&nbsp; Choose Income Tax Rate:</span><br><br>
<div class="custom-select" style="width:400px">
<select id="itrate">
<option value="0">Choose income tax rate as per your requirement...</option>
<option value=".03">3% -Transportation, IT services etc...</option>
<option value=".08">8% -Services|Companies|Filer</option>
<option value=".1">10% -Services|Individuals|Filer</option>
<option value=".07">7% -Contract Services|Companies|Filer</option>
<option value=".075">7.5% -Contract Services|Individuals|Filer</option>

</select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is when I click my 'select options' div for the first time, it gives very ugly slide effect. Plus according to this script, when the user clicks anywhere outside the div, the select options menu should automatically hide and that's not happening after applying this 'slideToggle()' function.

PS: I copied the styling code (css+javascript) from w3schools website. I only added an ID in its javascript code and tried to apply slideToggle() effect on it. Please guide me where I'm making a mistake???

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements in the HTML with the same `id` attribute, which is what you're doing here: `b.setAttribute("ID", "selectItems");`

Comment: @freefaller So what would be the solution?

Comment: @TaimoorAhmed if you add a click listener to the document, you have to add a preventDefault() to the other buttons' clickListeners or else it will trigger the document click

Comment: @Taimoor - use a class instead, then you can target your `slideToggle` on that class

Comment: @DiogoPeres In my script where should I add preventDefault()?

Comment: @freefaller I tried it with classes too. Can you please guide me which class exactly I should be using from my script?